# Can someone explain what the contextmenu attribute in HTML5 does?

Tags: html

can someone explain what the the contextmenu attribute does and if it can be used with all the HTML elements and can someone point me to some online demos/examples?

Comment: @TJ https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#context-menus

Answer (score 3):

The [contextmenu](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#context-menus) attribute refers to the [`<menu>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#menus) element the user agent should render when a context menu is requested by the user (e.g. using the right mouse button or the `Menu`/`Hyper` key on modern keyboards.

You can find an example [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/tablecontextmenu_source.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can see how it may look like in this demo:
https://bug617528.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=554309

At the time of writing only FireFox 8 supports it.

Answer (score 2):

The context menu appears when the user right-clicks on an interface element. The `contextmenu` attribute is the ID of a `<menu>` element to open when the user right clicks on the element with this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Quoting for you to understand easily:**

> The contextmenu attribute allows you
>   to display a menu without taking up
>   valuable UI space for the menu. It is
>   a menu which fires on events, such as
>   mouseup or keyup providing a bubble
>   menu which provides options and
>   actions based on those selections.

**Source:** http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-globals-and-you/

**See official link for more information:**

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

The contextmenu should be used on an input field to specify which menu element is for the field. The menus look sort of like the right click menu or a dropdown box however they are not implemented in any browser yet so you should avoid using them.

This may help clear things up:
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/interactive-elements.html

Answer (score -1):

```
<form name="npc">
 <label>Character name: <input name="char" type="text" contextmenu="namemenu" required></label>
 <menu type="context" id="namemenu">
  <command label="Pick random name" onclick="document.forms.npc.elements.char.value = getRandomName()">
  <command label="Prefill other fields based on name" onclick="prefillFields(document.forms.npc.elements.char.value)">
 </menu>
</form>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#context-menus