# HTML5 contextmenu attribute question?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone explain what the contextmenu attribute in HTML5 does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119106/can-someone-explain-what-the-contextmenu-attribute-in-html5-does)

Can someone explain the contextmenu attribute to me? Can it be used with all the element or no?