# How do I use the attribute "context menu" in HTML5?

Tags: html, menu, contextmenu

How do I use the attribute "contextmenu" in HTML5?
Is there any example online?

Comment: that might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121351/html5-contextmenu-attribute-question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121351/html5-contextmenu-attribute-question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121351/html5-contextmenu-attribute-question

There are many links and examples given in above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/html5-context-menus-in-firefox-screencast-and-code/

But I'm having trouble getting to work 100% for me.